# save table date column filter criteria

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I'm trying to save filters from a table which has FilterMode on, in order to restore them after some work done.
How can I save filter's criteria for an Excel table **date column**, when **AutoFilterDateGrouping** is **true**?
I always get

`error (1004) trying to read .Criteria1 or .Criteria2 values for .Operator = 7 (xlFilterValues)`

Using this code:

`FilterArray(i, 1) = .Criteria1`
 or
`FilterArray(i, 1) = .Criteria2`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub ReDoAutoFilter()
Dim w As Worksheet
Dim filterArray()
Dim currentFiltRange As String
Dim col As Integer

Set w = ActiveSheet

' Capture AutoFilter settings
With w.AutoFilter
    currentFiltRange = .Range.Address
    With .Filters
        ReDim filterArray(1 To .Count, 1 To 3)
        For f = 1 To .Count
            With .Item(f)
                If .On Then
                    filterArray(f, 1) = .Criteria1
                    If .Operator Then
                        filterArray(f, 2) = .Operator
                        filterArray(f, 3) = .Criteria2
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        Next f
    End With
End With
w.AutoFilterMode = False

' Code here

' Restore Filter settings
For col = 1 To UBound(filterArray(), 1)
    If Not IsEmpty(filterArray(col, 1)) Then
        If filterArray(col, 2) Then
            w.Range(currentFiltRange).AutoFilter field:=col, _
            Criteria1:=filterArray(col, 1), _
            Operator:=filterArray(col, 2), _
            Criteria2:=filterArray(col, 3)
        Else
            w.Range(currentFiltRange).AutoFilter field:=col, _
            Criteria1:=filterArray(col, 1)
        End If
    End If
Next col
End Sub
```

Comment: sorry, didn't work. date column doesn't have .Criteria1 or .Criteria2 (they are in error) when date is grouped by year and with .Operator = 7. There are other properties you know for a date field (auto)filter?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Naveen,

I'm using Excel 2013 and ... sorry, but, running the code gave me the same error (1004) at line "filterArray(f, 1) = .Criteria1" (it's about a **Date** column).

The fact is that for a Date column that has a filter based on the grouping of dates by years (**AutoFilterDateGrouping is true**) and .Operator 7 the solution you gave doesn't work.

I think it didn't work because for Date columns there is no .Criteria1 or .Criteria2.

Other solution I tried is using custom views but for a workbook, having ListObjects inside, it isn't possible to save filter using custom views.

The only "solution" I found is to add a new row inside the table using **Insert** method from Range (EntireRow).

Is not elegant but it works.

I wasn't able until now to find the right properties of the (auto)filter for a **Date** table column.

Comment: I think it should work by setting AutoFilterDateGrouping to False.